# How can I get the latest emails from all folders with exchangelib?

Tags: exchangelib

Currently, I use

```
latest_mails = account.inbox.filter(datetime_received__gt=emails_since)
```

But it seems to miss received emails which are in subfolders.

Printing all folders with

```
for f in account.root.get_folders():
    print(f)
```

gives something like

```
Calendar (Kalender)
Contacts (Kontakte)
Contacts (Vorgeschlagene Kontakte)
Folder (AllItems)
Folder (Calendar Logging)
Folder (Common Views)
Folder (Conversation Action Settings)
Folder (Deferred Action)
Folder (Deletions)
Folder (Erinnerungen)
Folder (ExchangeSyncData)
Folder (Finder)
Folder (Infected Items)
Folder (Journal)
Folder (Location)
Folder (MailboxAssociations)
Folder (Notizen)
Folder (Recipient Cache)
Folder (Recoverable Items)
Folder (Schedule)
Folder (Shortcuts)
Folder (Spooler Queue)
Folder (System)
Folder (Versions)
Folder (Views)
Folder (WorkingSet)
Messages (Postausgang)
Messages (Posteingang)
Messages (foo)
Messages (bar)
Messages (something is)
Messages (here)
Messages (Gelöschte Elemente)
Messages (Gesendete Elemente)
Messages (Junk-E-Mail)
Messages (Meine Kontakte)
Messages (MyContactsExtended)
Messages (Nachverfolgte E-Mail-Verarbeitung)
Messages (Zugang)
Tasks (Aufgaben)
Tasks (Aufgabensuche)
```

So I only want to look at the "Messages" folders, but at all of them. Is that possible (without using `account.root.get_folders()`) and looping over the results (which took about 5 minutes)

Comment: See also: https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/30#issuecomment-257429078 - but I don't know where `Messages` comes from.

Comment: `from exchangelib.folders import Messages` seems to be it

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that `.filter()` only works on the folder you call it on, not subfolders. I'm pretty sure EWS only supports searching one folder at a time.

You should be able to do something like this to speed things up a little bit:

```
from exchangelib.folders import Messages

for f in account.folders[Message]:
    for i in f.filter(datetime_received__gt=emails_since):
        print(i)
```

But `Folder` type folders can also contain `Message` items, so depending on your needs you may also have to visit those.

`f.supported_item_models` will tell you which item types a given folder can contain.

Comment: Actually, EWS *does* support filtering on multiple folders in a single request. exchangelib now supports this using the `FolderCollection` class. See https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#searching